# SVN Diff Coloring into Vim

Tags: svn, vim

```
svn diff somefile > check.txt
```

When pushing svn diff into a text file, the output maintains the text coloring when viewing within vim. Is this a vim plugin that was installed with svn, or are their special character encodings to force syntax highlighting in a text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a vim syntax highlighting. You can turn it off inside vim with the command

```
:set syntax=off
```

Answer (score 1):

Vim has a syntax highlighting plugin for the diff format. There's no color codes actually in the diff file.

Answer (score 0):

Another sort of solution, vimdiff:
 
 `svn cat file > tmp

vimdiff tmp file`


or less (without writing to file)

`svn diff file | less -R`

I like the last one because then I don't need to care about temporary files. This kind of operation when needed, rarely I need to put diff into the file.